# Not able to deploy EAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, struts2, ejb-3.0

I am developing a web module in struts2 framework and ejb module in eclipse with hibernate as ORM framework.
Every time when I modify my ejb module I have to package it into jar and include it in my web module /WEB-INF/lib folder in order to run my whole application. Though the application worked fine in this way but it was really time consuming. So I tried to map them in a EAR module. But when I try to run EAR module. It gives below exceptions

```
2016-12-24 13:23:43,992 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler] (default task-4) Exception occurred during processing request: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error: javax.ejb.EJBException: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/HibernateException
    at com.ebs.persistence.dao.UserDao.<clinit>(UserDao.java:16)
    at com.ebs.business.service.UserAuthorisationBusinessService.getUserProfile(UserAuthorisationBusinessService.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException from [Module "deployment.EBS.ear.EBS-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 179 more
```

Below is where I suspect to get the exception

```
private static SessionFactory sessfct = SessionFactoryGenerator.getSessionFactory();
```

It seems to be some issue with classloader. Since earlier it use to work fine with same set of jars when EAR was not in the picture. I am probably new to EAR. Below is the structure of application.xml

```
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>EBS-web.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>EBS-web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>EBS-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
```

I also tried including all the jars in EAR lib folder but no success was achieved

Answer (score 0):

You can not deploy your `EAR` file because the following class could not be found.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.HibernateException
```

Make sure you have `hibernate` libraries in your server lib folder or packed in your `EAR` lib archive.